# no route matches post for simple search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Listing model code

```
def self.search(search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    find(:all, :conditions => ['franchisename LIKE ? or longdescription LIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
end
```

Home controller

```
  def search
    @results = Listing.search params[:search]
  end
```

Route

```
 get 'home/search'
```

Home/index.html.erb search form

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'home', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'indexsearch' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

Home/search.html.erb search results

```
<%= @results.each do |result| %>
<%= result.franchisename %>
<%= result.shortdescription %>
<% end %>
```

Error: No route matches [POST] "/home/search"

I just want it so that I can type in my search query on the home page and then upon submission it redirects to a results page containing the results. I followed a guide initially but maybe it was outdated, though it doesn't say. Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1):

Just defined the form_tag in the following way.

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'home', :action => 'search'), :method => 'get' do %>
```

Hope your problem will be resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should specify controller and action in to your routes like below:

```
 get 'home/search' => 'home#search'
```

Hope this resolve your problem!!!

Cheers!!!